# @Version in MongoDB Limit

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I am using @Version to handle optimist lock
And I have a question, what happened when it is 2147483647, or max number expression in Long?

In the most example @Version is used with Long and in MongoDB is converted to Int32.

Just make A LOT OF updates